# Running NWN1 (x86) on Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, qemu, games

I've been trying to get qemu to load this x86 [Debian image](https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/i386/) built for qemu on my Pi 2, and I'm wondering if someone knowledgeable can give me some advice.

I want to run a Neverwinter Nights (x86 binary) dedicated server inside the emulated Debian image (or any distro that supports NWN1 server emulated on ARMv7).

I tried installing qemu via `apt-get install qemu` on Raspbian. The Debian image seems to start since 25% of my processor is active, but the console screen remains blank. I'm using the command: `qemu-system-i386`.

Answer (score 1):

Your RPi isn't powerful enough for the task. Emulating an x86 processor on ARM is incredibly resource intensive. Add a game (even an older game) on top of that, and your RPi just won't be able to keep up.

You mention you're using 25% of your processor. That means that qemu instance is taking up 100% of one of the available four cores. Since games (especially older games) tend to be designed for single core (CPU wise) utilization, adding cores to QEMU won't really help you any.